# Writing custom formatters for slick grid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

While writing custom cell formatters

```
 function PercentCompleteFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext)
```

This is the basic definition we have to follow.can i get explanation about dataContext argument in slick grid.What it actually represents.

The exact code for this is

```
function PercentCompleteFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
if (value == null || value === "") {
  return "-";
} else if (value < 50) {
  return "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "%</span>";
} else {
  return "<span style='color:green'>" + value + "%</span>";
}
}
```

I just want what dataContext in above code represents

Answer (score 5):

"dataContext" is the data item that the cell for the row being rendered is bound to.

Comment: In this example, the PercentCompleteRenderer is displaying the percent complete field of a task.  "dataContext" is that task.

Comment: Task you mean complete row in the grid

Comment: Yes.  The basic examples on the SlickGrid wiki show tasks in the grid, so that's what I used.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more simple,

I wrote this function where i defined my slickgrid and then passed my function to the **formatter**

```
    function roundOffValuesFormatter (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
        if(dataContext[cellID] || dataContext[cellID]) {
         return Math.round(value*100)/100;  
        } 
    }
```

and now call this formatter,

```
{id:'cellID', field:'cellID', name:'Name', width:90, editor:Slick.Editors.Text, formatter: roundOffValuesFormatter}
```

**Now, customize it according to your requirement.**