# Slickgrid: Change cell html onCellChange

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I want to change the edited cell HTML whene it's invalide, I'm trying to do it in the `onCellChange` event and gettind the active cell node throught `getActiveCellNode` and change it's HTML, the problem is that the DOM changes do not apply.

Here is the code:

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (evt, args) {
        var $cell = $(grid.getActiveCellNode());

        if (validateCell(grid.getActiveCell())) {
            $cell.html('<div style="background: #FFCCCC" title="This field is invalid">Field invalid!</div>');
        }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you will need to do is write some code.  If you have done that already, maybe you could share - otherwise it's going to be hard for people to help you figure out what's wrong

Comment: @Tibrogargan I updated the question. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

```html
//row equal grid row
//cell equal grid cell
//value is the value from the Dataview if you are using dv if not value of data in grid
//columnDef is the colum defination fro the colunm you are on 
//dataContext is the object that makes up the row ie on item in dataview
function InvalidFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
if(value == ckeck){ //dont know what your valid state is but you shoulld get the point 
return '<span style="background: #FFCCCC" title="This field is invalid">Field invalid!</span>'
}
//or 
if(dataContext[some propertiy from the dataview or row] == ckeck){ //dont know what your valid state is but you shoulld get the point 
return '<span style="background: #FFCCCC" title="This field is invalid">Field invalid!</span>'
}
return '<span  title="valid">'+value+'</span>';
}
//more here https://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example2-formatters.html
```

This should be achieved using a custom formatter example [Custom Formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527596/writing-custom-formatters-for-slick-grid)